# Golang auth. Parsing JWT: illegal base64 data at input byte 0

Tags: json, go, authentication, jwt, base64

I am making an authentication form on my web app.

First, I send the form data to server, it produces the token and I store it in the localStorage

Then, I want to redirect from form page to the home page. Here is the JavaScript that sends the token to server so that I would be seen as an authorized user on the home page:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', '/')
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', localStorage.token)
xhr.send()
xhr.onload  = () => {
if(xhr.status >= 400) {
    console.log("error")
  }
}

xhr.onerror = () => {
    console.log("error")
}
```

Then I want to check the token and show the home page. Here is the Golang func for it:

```
func (h *Handler) Home_page(c *gin.Context) {
header := c.GetHeader("Authorization")
    if header != "" {
        _, err := h.services.Authorization.ParseToken(header)
        if err != nil {
            newErrorResponse(c, http.StatusUnauthorized, err.Error())
            return
        }
        c.HTML(
            http.StatusOK,
            "home_page.gohtml",
            gin.H{
                "IsAuth": true,
            },
        )
        return
    }
}
```

ParseToken func:

```
func (s *AuthService) ParseToken(accessToken string) (int, error) {
    token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(accessToken, &tokenClaims{}, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
            return nil, errors.New("invalid signing method")
        }
        return []byte(signingKey), nil //signingKey is a string with random elements
    })
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    claims, ok := token.Claims.(*tokenClaims)
    if !ok {
        return 0, errors.New("token claims are not of type *tokenClaims")
    }

    return claims.UserId, nil
}
```

The problem is that I get this error:

*ERRO[0001] illegal base64 data at input byte 0*

I already checked the token on the jwt.io, it shows that the token is verified, maybe the problem is in the type of string that I am passing as a token.

Another problem is that if I don't check the error returning from token validation,  the home page doesn't show with this error:

*http: panic serving [::1]:50490: write tcp [::1]:8083->[::1]:50490: write: broken pipe*

I am new to Golang, was struggling with this problem, though it seems typical.

I would be very thankful for any help on how to process the token or to redirect from the authentication form!

**Edit:** I am using the [https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4](https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt)

Comment: I suggest you start by logging the value of `header` and verifying what it actually is.

Comment: @Crowman, thanks for your answer! I have logged the value of header. It prints: 
`"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NDE2MTMxOTcsImlhdCI6MTY0MTU2OTk5NywiVXNlcklkIjoyfQ.NV7Aj5mwJgeOFmhL3UP0srXtk1lD8cAgC2MxxhaOF6c" ` This value is a valid token (I checked it on jwt.io with the tick that I use the secret base64)

Comment: But the issue still occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, this issue:
*illegal base64 data at input byte 0*

Was solved by changing the way I stored the token. I was storing in the local storage like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
```

I changed it to the next line and the error disappeared:

```
localStorage.token = data.token
```

(data is the JSON with token that my server returns)

Now if I log the value of token it appears without commas. @Crowman, thank you for answer!

*Edit*: The second issue with broken pipe occurred, because I was not waiting for the answer on the client side. So now I changed the JS code to wait for the response but still I am struggling with how to show the html page that I receive from server using JavaScript.